# Problems converting DataSet string to Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've retrieved a dataset from the northwind db with a view to displaying out via a webgrid in the view. However when I instantiate the customer object it errors at converting the 'id' field to an int value. Here is my code...

```
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter;
        DataSet myDataSet;

        string cmdString = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle FROM Customers";

        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PETERPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
        myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, conn);

        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Customers");

        foreach (DataRow dr in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer() { id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), co_name = dr[1].ToString(), name = dr[2].ToString(), title = dr[3].ToString() });
        }



        return View(customers);
    }
```

The list declared at the top of the controller file...

```
private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
```

However I've a number of ways around this but inside the foreach the     `id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString())` always errors, it will run fine if I don't use the ID however.

Here is the error message...

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]    System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +10726387    System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145    System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
>   Movie.Controllers.HelloController.List() in
>   c:\Users\peter_000\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Movie\Movie\Controllers\HelloController.cs:52
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101

The objective is to move all this out to a webservice and call it as a service. This should probably be trivial but I cant seem to find my way round it.

Can anyone advise or suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: What does `dr[0]` contain? Have you used the debugger to see the value?

Comment: Have you tried without the use of ToString() like id = dr[0] or you could use int.TryParse(dr[0].ToString(), out id)?

Comment: I did try these first time couple of attempts, the below solution worked fine for me. thanks for your comments guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you converting it to a string in the first place? Assuming it's *actually* an `int` type, just cast:

```
// Property names changed to be more sensible
customers.Add(new Customer {
    Id = (int) dr[0],
    CompanyName = (string) dr[1],
    ContactName = (string) dr[2],
    Title = (string) dr[3]
});
```

Of course if it's a 64-bit integer, cast it to `long` (etc).

Avoid string conversions wherever possible - just because everything exposes a `ToString` method shouldn't be viewed as an invitation to call it at every opportunity.